# Best way to extract string between underscores using Perl

Tags: string, perl, split, extract

I have something like:

```
$string = '/mfsi_rpt/files/mfsi/reports/bval/bval_parlcont_pck_m_20130430.pdf';
```

I would like to extract the parlcont from the string (the word between the 2nd and 3rd underscore).

What is the best way to achieve this using Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you first take out the filename from the file path using [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) then you can use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to take out the desired name.

```
use strict;

use File::Basename;

my $string = "/mfsi_rpt/files/mfsi/reports/bval/bval_parlcont_pck_m_20130430.pdf";

my $data = ( split( /_/,  basename($string) ))[1];
```

Output:

```
 parlcont
```

Answer (score 3):

You can match this with a regular expression, by combining greedy and non-greedy matches, and using capturing parenthesis to extract the part you're interested in:

```
if( $string =~ m:.+/.*?_(.+?)_:) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

The ".+/" is a greedy match, which will gobble up everything up to the last / to get past the directory components.

Then the ".*?_" is non-greedy, so it will take everything up to the first _

Then "(.+?)_" is another non-greedy to match and capture everything up to the next _